# Is it bad form to have "operator>" delegate to "operator<"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I wrote this in a recent program:

```
friend bool operator<(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b) {
    // Lots of comparison code here
}

friend bool operator>(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b) {
    return b < a;
}
```

It works fine when I run the program, but is this bad form? Is there any reason I should not be doing this? Or is there something I should be doing instead?

Normally I would write `operator<` and `operator>` completely separate, but because the code in `operator<` is long, I decided to take this shortcut.

Also note that speed is of the essence in this program.

Comment: So long as it makes sense for your use case; I see nothing wrong with it. Seen it done many times. Only would be an issue in cases where `a < b` does not mean the same as `b > a`, but I'm assuming that's not the case here.

Comment: Not only is this not bad form, it is good form. It's better to write all of the comparison operators in terms of just one (i.e. all of `>`, `<=`, and `>=` in terms of `<`, and `!=` in terms of `==`) because it reduces the chance of error (copy-paste errors are real and cause a lot of bugs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the comparison operators in terms of less than is common in order to avoid writing the same code over and over (or copy/pasting) which is a source of bugs:

```cpp
bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    //Actual comparison of members
}

bool operator>=(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return !(a < b);
}

bool operator>(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return b < a;
}

bool operator<=(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return !(b < a); //Can also do !(a > b)
}
```

Here comes the hiccup though, equality can be defined in terms of less than, but it means something different than explicit equality if you require strict weak ordering:

```cpp
bool operator==(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return !(a < b) && !(b < a);
}

bool operator!=(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return !(a == b);
}
```

OR

```cpp
bool operator==(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    //Actual comparison of members.
}

bool operator!=(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return !(a == b);
}
```